# Retrieve value from web.config system.web section

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my .net application `web.config` file, under the system.web section,

```
<system.web>
     <membership configSource="membership.config" />
</system.web>
```

and in my membership.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
    <add applicationName="xxx"  
         testing="3" />
 </providers>
</membership>
```

In my application code, how do I get the value for "testing"?

Comment: U can use XmlDocument to parse the xml and get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use build-in SqlMembershipProvider:

```
var appName = ((SqlMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider).ApplicationName;
```

If you implement your own custom membership provider, you can get the value from **Initialize** method
E.g:

```
public class YouMembershipProvider: MembershipProvider
{
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
     var appName = config["applicationName"];
}
```

Your configuration should looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<membership defaultProvider="myMembershipProvider">
    <add name="myMembershipProvider" type="TestApp.YouMembershipProvider, TestApp" ApplicationName="xxx"/>
 </providers>
</membership>
```